# Combat-centric 1st or 2nd level adventure with a Native American theme?

Tags: game-recommendation, adnd-1e, published-adventures

I have played for quite a few years, but now I want to DM. I have a local area set up involving a small group of islands. I have already run a 0 lvl adventure, but now I want to follow it up. So I'm looking for an easily adaptable adventure with an island setting and **Native American theme**. Also, I know the one player specifically likes getting to the action, so I'm trying to avoid adventures that have puzzles, mazes, and other then fighting challenges. I've played mostly with AD&D 1st edition and would like to keep it as close to that as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Luke, welcome to the site.  You may not know this but there are probably hundreds of first or second level adventures that are or could be set on islands.  Please review our guidance on recommendation questions designed to make questions like this useful. Without even basics like system and edition this will for sure get closed - think about more specifically what you want and edit the question to reflect that. http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic

Comment: That's way better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you've already done for the level 0 adventure, there's something I'll recommend.  It's actually a series of three linked adventures/sourcebooks called [Jakandor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_&_Dragons_campaign_settings#Jakandor) (Island of War/Isle of Destiny/Land of Legend) for second edition AD&D.  You can play the Charonti, the pseudo-Egyptian necromancers, or the Knorr, the barbarians, in their struggle for the island kingdom of Jakandor.  Your group has to choose one or the other faction, in your case the Knorr.  The Knorr are an iron-age people who seem to be a cross between Plains Indians and Vikings, with a little Celtic thrown in.  It should provide fodder for a whole mini-campaign.  It is of course out of print but available on various sites.